# ORA-20031: Java Development Disabled in Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle

I am getting below exception. How to enable java development in oracle?

```
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
 [java] ORA-20031: Java Development Disabled
 [java] ORA-06512: at line 4
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an artefact of an Oracle security patch. There is a trigger which prevents the compilation of Java objects in the database. If you really need to do this ask your DBAs to run `dbms_java_dev.enable()`. [Find out more](https://blogs.oracle.com/upgrade/the-ojvm-patching-saga-and-how-to-solve-it-part-iii)